# Exact difference between two dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the exact difference of two dates in respective years.

For example:

There are two columns having dates:

```
1991-05-21          1997-07-20
```

So the difference when calculated manually is 6 years and 2 months. So, is it possible to get 6.2 as the difference in the result column?

The syntax I have used is : `timestampdiff(year,date1,date2)` which gives me 7 as the difference.

Comment: And 6 years 11 months should be 6.11?

Comment: You are better off using DATEDIFF and then dividing by 365.25.

Comment: Why is it 6 years and **2** months instead of a **1** month?

Answer (score 1):

The `timestampdiff()` function always rounds up to the nearest unit you selected. If you want this level of granularity, you'd be better off getting the difference in months, and then dividing it.

```
timestampdiff(MONTH, '1991-05-21', '1997-07-20') / 12 as difference
```

Comment: Sure, let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

This works better:

`concat(timestampdiff(year,columname1,columname2), '.' , mod(timestampdiff(month,columname1,columname2),12)) as columname from table_name`.